# pandas - swap rows between dataframes with column condition

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to exchange the whole row in df1 where column x has a specific value with the whole row from df2 where column x has a specific value. Printing df1 I got NaN in this row I try to exchange. Is there a plausible explanation for this? Can I do such an exchange based on specific values in columns? Any help is more than welcome.

```py
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'x': [1, 2, 3], 'y': [3, 4, 5]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'x': [3223, 323212, 13242], 'y': [41233, 54, 5532]})
df1[df1["x"]==1] = df2[df2["x"]==323212]
df1 #contains NaN and not the values from df2[df2["x"]==323212]
```

Comment: `df1.loc[df1["x"]==1, "x"] = df2.loc[df2["x"]==323212, "x"].iat[0]`?

Answer (score 0):

`pandas` has an data integrity mechanism which aligns indexes, meaning that values are are attempting to align based on index location where the righthand side `df2[df2["x"]==323212]` comes from index 1 so it is attempting to go to index 1 on the lefthand side. But there is no index 1 on the lefthand side only index 0. Therefore the data is considered missing (the pandas representation of which is `NaN`).

Operations which produce unindexed collections like [`values`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.values.html) or [`to_numpy()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.to_numpy.html#pandas.Series.to_numpy) can be used to break this alignment:

```
df1[df1["x"] == 1] = df2[df2["x"] == 323212].values
```

`df1`:

```
        x   y
0  323212  54
1       2   4
2       3   5
```

---

This can be confusing as something like:

```
df1[df1["x"] == 2] = df2[df2["x"] == 323212]
```

works as expected since the indexes happen align correctly (both index 1):

`df1`:

```
        x   y
0       1   3
1  323212  54
2       3   5
```

And something like this:

```
df1[df1['x'].isin([1, 3])] = df2[df2["x"].isin([3223, 323212])]
```

Appears to only partially work:

`df1`:

```
        x        y
0  3223.0  41233.0
1     2.0      4.0
2     NaN      NaN
```

However, all cases are the result of this index alignment placing the values in the "correct" location based on index.